# Hide view in specific CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, collectionview

I have question how to implement this stuff in right way.
So far I done

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let indexPatha = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

            let changeCell = collectionView .cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPatha) as! BarCollectionViewCell
            changeCell.addNewBottleSecondButton.alpha = 0
}
```

But when I swipe until cell is hidden, I am getting error, unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, and still this doesn't looks like how I want to make it.
I want to achieve that when I have more then one cell, I want to hide one specific view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work in your flow to handle this in cellForRowAtIndexPath instead?

After your initialize your cell:

```
    cell.addNewBottleSecondButton.hidden = (indexPath.row == 0) && (dataItems.count > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cell has been scrolled off the screen it may not exist anymore due to Apple's dequeue/re-use optimizations.   Previously when confronted with this problem, I've had to set a state variable and handle the UI change in cellForRow if the cell didn't exist when trying to change the cell's UI.

Comment: Thank you for explanation ! =)